# CSS apply position relative ONLY IF unset (ie don't override position absolute)

Tags: css, css-position

I have a "card" class where the point is to make something look like a material design card:

```
  .card {
    position: relative;  /** <--- issue if it overwrites position: absolute **/
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    
    /** card shadow is absolute positioned (and needed for mix-blend-mode) **/
    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      content: "";
      inset: 0;
      mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    }
  }
```

Due to the use of an absolutely positioned `::before` item, the card must ***in the very least*** be positioned relatively.  If it's already set as absolute, than this is unnecessary.

---

Is it possible to only have the `.card` class override position if it's not set?  Something like the opposite of `!important`

Comment: Why not make selector with `position: absolute` more specific than the one with `position: relative` then?

Comment: in this case, that would be a large-scale refactor and would create long-term tech debt for other devs to work around it